# React-Router UrlParameter with default value not showing active

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-bootstrap, react-router-redux

I have a race results app that has a NavBar that shows one "All Results" `Nav.Link` option to show all the results, and one "Add Result" `Nav.Link` option to allow you to enter a result. The twist is that if I click on the "Add Result" link directly, it should treat it as one where I enter the race number and look it up in the entries, but if I'm in the results page and I click an entry there, it should go to the "Add Result" page with all the entry info filled it.

I got that all working by using a Url Parameter in my routing, and so when you click the "All Results" link, it goes to `/result/0` but in the "All Results" table if you click an entry, it does a `dispatch(push('/result/' + id));`

The only problem with all that is that when it follows the `/result/999999` link, it doesn't make the matching `Nav.Link` active. It does when I click the "Add Result" link to `/result0`. I assume it's just matching the current url to the urls in the `Nav.Link`s. Do I really have to track that I'm in the "All Results" page and set the `active` property on the `Nav.Link` myself or is there some way Router can do it for me?

```
              <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/results' exact>
              All Results
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/result/0' exact>
              Add Result
              </Nav.Link>
...
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={AllEntriesWrapper} />
            <Route path='/results' exact component={AllResultsWrapper} />
            <Route path='/result/:entryId' exact component={AddResult} />
          </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work, I made the following changes

- Changed the link to `<Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/result'>`, removing the `0` parameter and the `exact` keyword.
- Added a 4th route like `<Route path='/results/' exact component{AddResult}/>`
- Made sure the AddResult component handled a undefined `ownProps.match.params.entryId` the same way it had been handling `'0'` before.